# Use density to set color and size of points using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just want to set the color and size of the point.
I've found quite a few posts but nothing I was able to reverse engineer.
Is it possible?

```
require(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) #+ xlim(0, 3)
d + stat_bin(aes(size = ..density.., color=..density..),
             binwidth = 0.1,geom = "point",
             position="jitter")  +
     guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 10)))
```

Edit: I think I got it, but now my question becomes is what I did correct or a hack? New code:

```
require(ggplot2)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(price)) #+ xlim(0, 3)
d + stat_bin(aes(size = ..density.., color=..density..),
             binwidth = 0.1,geom = "point",
             position="jitter")  +
    guides(col = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16,16,16,16,16),
                                                  size = c(2,3,4,5,6))))
```

Answer (score 2):

This produces a plot without error on my device:

```
d + stat_bin(aes(size = ..density.., color= ..density..), 
             binwidth = 0.1,geom = "point", position="jitter")
```

If you need something different you should make clear what such differences might be [image]